# Xamarin.Forms ListView inside StackLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a fairly simple XAML form in my Xamarin project, which is supposed to show two views packed in a vertical `StackLayout`, a `CameraView` at the top and a `ListView` at the bottom. The `CameraView` shall use up most of the space. The `ListView` shall not exceed 4-5 items, but will change during runtime. Here's the XAML I've got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="Foo.CamPage"
         xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:Foo.Controls">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

        <ctrl:CameraView HeightRequest="2000"/>

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView>
                  <ListView.ItemsSource>
                      <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Entry 1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Entry 2</x:String>
                      </x:Array>
                  </ListView.ItemsSource>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

As you can see, my first idea was to put the `ListView` into another nested `StackLayout`. I also played with the `HeightRequest` of the `CameraView` However, I don't want to set a specific height of the camera view, I want the `ListView` to take up as much space as needed and the `CameraView` to adapt accordingly. Is it possible to define percentages in the sizes?

If it helps, here's the `CameraView`:

```
namespace Foo.Controls
{
    public class CameraView : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CameraProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "Camera",
                returnType: typeof(CameraOptions),
                declaringType: typeof(CameraView),
                defaultValue: CameraOptions.Rear);

        public CameraOptions Camera
        {
            get { return (CameraOptions)GetValue(CameraProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CameraProperty, value); }
        }

        public Func<Task<ImageSource>> TakePhotoAsync { set; get; }

        public Func<CameraOptions, bool> SwitchCamera { set; get; }
    }
}
```

And this is the associated iOS renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraView), typeof(CamPreviewRenderer))]
namespace Foo.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CamPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CameraView, UICamPreview>
    {
        UICamPreview uiCameraPreview;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                uiCameraPreview = new UICamPreview(e.NewElement.Camera);
                SetNativeControl(uiCameraPreview);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
                uiCameraPreview.Tapped -= OnCameraPreviewTapped;
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Subscribe
                uiCameraPreview.Tapped += OnCameraPreviewTapped;
            }
        }

        void OnCameraPreviewTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (uiCameraPreview.IsPreviewing)
            {
                uiCameraPreview.CaptureSession.StopRunning();
                uiCameraPreview.IsPreviewing = false;
            }
            else
            {
                uiCameraPreview.CaptureSession.StartRunning();
                uiCameraPreview.IsPreviewing = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the `UICamPreview`:

```
namespace Foo.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class UICamPreview : UIView
    {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer previewLayer;
        CameraOptions cameraOptions;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Tapped;

        public AVCaptureSession CaptureSession { get; private set; }

        public bool IsPreviewing { get; set; }

        public UICamPreview(CameraOptions options)
        {
            cameraOptions = options;
            IsPreviewing = false;
            Initialize();
        }

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            previewLayer.Frame = rect;
        }

        public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
            OnTapped();
        }

        protected virtual void OnTapped()
        {
            var eventHandler = Tapped;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            CaptureSession = new AVCaptureSession();
            previewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(CaptureSession)
            {
                Frame = Bounds,
                VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill
            };

            var videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
            var cameraPosition = (cameraOptions == CameraOptions.Front) ? AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front : AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back;
            var device = videoDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Position == cameraPosition);

            if (device == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            NSError error;
            var input = new AVCaptureDeviceInput(device, out error);
            CaptureSession.AddInput(input);
            Layer.AddSublayer(previewLayer);
            CaptureSession.StartRunning();
            IsPreviewing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: CameraView control refresh correctly the view?. Sure that when Xamarin draws cameraview is to late, stacklayout's FillAndExpand has invaded all the view. If you put only camera control it appears ok?

Comment: Yeah the CameraView itself works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put those views into Grid with 2 rows. The one that you want to use as much space as you require set Height to Auto and the other view that suppose to take up the remaining space set Height to *. Something like this

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
 <Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ctrl:CameraView Grid.Row="0"/>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView>
              <ListView.ItemsSource>
                  <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Entry 1</x:String>
                    <x:String>Entry 2</x:String>
                  </x:Array>
              </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
   </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
```

Please bear in mind that ListView is a very buggy when it comes to layout. You might have to play around with setting Hard coded values for Height anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry man, the Grid approach looked so promising, but it's not working. The ListView takes up all the space. The outer StackLayout is redundant, right? Will a TableView make things better?

Comment: Yes it is, try removing it and move the Grid.Row="1" into actual ListView and see if that helps. FillAndExpand option might have caused using up whole space.

Comment: Also try wrapping that cameraview into stacklayout with Fill and Expand options.

Comment: Any chance that parent StackLayout is not expanding? If i struggle with layouts i normally give Background colors to all my controls to see where the borders are ending. Try that and see where each control is ending. It would be easier to figure out for you which View is not expanding.

Comment: Oh wait! So you're saying the outer StackLayout is important? I removed it, because I thought this was redundant, too. If I set both heights to be `*`, both views share the same height. That's a start. I found you can also say `5*` for a view to be five times as big. However, the ListView never disappears, tho

Comment: Thats correct. (Number)* makes one view (Number) times bigger than other views in Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding OnLayout, usually code is like this.

```html
        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);



                if (!changed)
                    return;



                int msw = 50;
                int msh = 50;

                int layoutWidth = r - l;
                int layoutHeight = b - t;


                msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(layoutWidth, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
                msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(layoutHeight, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

                view.Measure(msw, msh);
                view.Layout(0, 0, layoutWidth, layoutHeight);


            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
               Logger.WriteException(ex);
            }
            
      }
```

Comment: No I haven't, yet! That looks promising, I'm gonna try this now. That's a method of `View` right?